# Can I install pantheon terminal in Ubuntu 14.04 or newer?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, pantheon

Is it possible to install Pantheon terminal from elementary OS on my Ubuntu 14.04 or newer LTS releases? If yes, how can I?

Comment: Why do you want to install it? Do you want the default Terminal to look like it?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In case you want your Terminal to look like Elementary OS' terminal, do the following -

Go to `Edit` -> `Profile Preferences`

Go to the `Colors` tab and uncheck `Use Colors from System Theme`

From the `Built-in Schemes` drop down menu, select `White on Black`

Go to the `Background` tab and select `Transparent Background`

Adjust the slider below according to your preference. Around 75% should look good.

Comment: He didn't ask about making the terminal *look* like Pantheon, he actually wants Pantheon.

Answer (score 15):

You can install it by running:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pantheon-terminal
```

The [ppa:elementary/stable](https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/ubuntu/stable) is recommended for LTS releases of Ubuntu.

The [ppa:elementary/daily](https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/ubuntu/daily) may be used for any currently supported releases of Ubuntu and has the newest and most unstable development of elementary. The Daily PPA is subject to critical bugs and should *not* be used except for testing purpose only.

Do note that, since Pantheon often uses a different version of GTK than Ubuntu (especially with LTS), this may impact your system with broader impact (IE: Gnome issues), so thar be dragons

Comment: Hm, no longer seems to work. Can't find the package.

Comment: As per suggested edit, I have indeed clarified that `pantheon-terminal` does exist on both PPAs at Launchpad.net. The elementary Stable PPA should be preferred for tested stable releases.

Comment: Tested installation of `pantheon-terminal` in Xubuntu 16.04. Just works; make sure to enable compositor, otherwise user will see a big black box appear in the background.

Answer (score 6):

Pantheon terminal requires gtk >= 3.12, but Ubuntu 14.04 comes with gtk 3.10

So at the moment it is not installable unless you want to add gnome3 staging ppa, which is not recommended and will probably break your system.

Comment: This is apparently still valid. The dependency error is seen when trying to install from the Stable PPA: `libgranite3:i386 depends on libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.12)` on 14.04 release.