# What is Elementary OS' default Terminal colour scheme?

Tags: themes, elementary, color-management

What is the Elementary OS’ default Terminal colour scheme?

How can I have the same on Ubuntu?

Comment: I @Terrance, no I speak about the Terminal colour scheme :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I install pantheon terminal in ubuntu 14.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/551881/can-i-install-pantheon-terminal-in-ubuntu-14-04)